# What is drag and drop as in "moving stuff around with a mouse" called as opposed to drag and drop as in data transfer?

Tags: c#, java, drag-and-drop, draggable

I'm trying to implement drag and drop in C# and Java in order to allow the user to move visual elements around with the mouse but all I'm finding on Google are tutorials about data transfer and copy paste. What would be better search terms?

Comment: Just to clarify with an example, I'm talking about something like this: http://jqueryui.com/demos/droppable/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.java-tips.org/java-se-tips/javax.swing/how-to-implement-drag-drop-functionality-in-your-applic.html

OR

http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-03-1999/jw-03-dragndrop.html?page=1

And search terms  on google you can use: drag drop component GUI java

Bests

Answer (score 1):

two Goodle searches to use, many useful results in first page of both.

"winforms drag and drop example"

"swing drag and drop example"